# Google Analytics version 4 API java maximum results

Tags: java, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

In Google Analytics API version 3 for Java there was a setMaxResults method:

```
  private static GaData executeDataQuery(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, // Table Id. ga: + profile id.
    "2012-01-01", // Start date.
    "2012-01-14", // End date.
    "ga:visits") // Metrics.
    .setDimensions("ga:source,ga:keyword")
    .setSort("-ga:visits,ga:source")
    .setFilters("ga:medium==organic")
    .setMaxResults(25)
    .execute();
```

}

How can I get maxResults using Google Analytics API version 4? I had a brief scan through the javadocs [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/analyticsreporting/v4/java/latest/) and cannot find a method to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the answer to my question: `request.setPageSize(6)` gives the max result I needed.